# Different watermark (objects) for certain pages

Tags: watermark, draftwatermark

Is it possible to load different watermark objects on certain pages?

Let say, I would like an image watermarking my first page and text watermark for the rest of the pages.

I am currently using the draftwatermark package.

(Sorry, I couldn't make the MWE since I think it is a bit hard for this case for me.)

Comment: did you try to change the options on the second page? Did it fail?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, were you referring about `stamp=false` and `stamp=true`?

Comment: If that is true, I've been trying that options, but I didn't know how to insert another object using the options.